# Official Spring Abbreviations

Tags: spring

May I know if there is an official abbreviations for Spring commonly use terms/annotation?

For example

```
@Component  - ExampleComp
@Service    - ExampleSvc
@Respository - ExampleRes
```

I work for a very anal organization that requires justification for all kinds of abbreviations.

An abbreviation (from Latin brevis, meaning short) is a shortened form of a word or phrase. Usually, but not always, it consists of a letter or group of letters taken from the word or phrase. For example, the word abbreviation can itself be represented by the abbreviation abbr., abbrv. or abbrev.

Comment: There a list of the Spring annotations here: http://www.techferry.com/articles/spring-annotations.html

Comment: i'm actually asking about their shortforms =x

Comment: Do you mean "annotation"? What is your organization so strict about? Abbreviations? Use of Java annotations? Use of external code libraries?

Answer (score 2):

These are not abbreviations , they are annotations (you can understand them as identifiers) to identify the pieces which can be scanned and registered at the time of context creation.

Moreover, they can be used interchangeably, but a general convention is to use the

@Repository for the Domain level objects, 
@Service for the Service layer classes in the ideal MVC implementation and 
@Component in general can be used for any component we want the bean context to be aware of.

If you can be more specific about what you want to ask, I might help you with a more clear answer.

**EDIT:**

If you want to see some examples of how these annotations can be used effectively in a classic Spring MVC web application, I am sure you need to see my article [Annotation Based Spring MVC](http://techieme.in/techieme/annotation-based-spring-mvc/)

Comment: for example a service.. ExampleService, I wish to make it shorter by using abbr. for Service.. Is there an official abbr for it? Example Svc

Comment: I am sorry, the ones I you know are the only available ones. Spring doesn't provide anything shorter than that. You can actually create your own, but I am sure you will not like to take  all that pain just to shorten the annotation name by few characters.

Comment: I am not changing the @Service.. merely the naming of the classes

Comment: Well I am sure u meant naming of the annotations. No you cannot use a dictionary kind of bahaviour to refer an annotation with some different name in Spring